# Laravel 5.6. PHPUnit. Order-insensitive assertJson() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-testing

In my business logic I don't care about the order of elements.

Here is my example of a test

```
$this->getJson('/api/order-attempts')
     ->assertJson([
         'data' => [
             ['status' => 'error'],
             ['status' => 'error'],
             ['status' => 'confirmed'],
             ['status' => 'confirmed'],
             ['status' => 'confirmed'],
         ],
     ])->isOk();
```

It fails from time to time only because of the order. I do NOT want to put sorting to the api, cause I don't need it.

Is it possible to `assertJsonIgnoringOrder()` somehow?

Comment: maybe seeJson works for you

Comment: `assertJsonFragment` does internally sort (essentially ignoring order) but it also matches partial JSON fragments so it may or may not work for you

Answer (score 2):

You can check the structure and alignment of json by using `assertSame()`

For example try this

```
 $this->assertSame(json_encode([
     'data' => [
         ['status' => 'error'],
         ['status' => 'error'],
         ['status' => 'confirmed'],
         ['status' => 'confirmed'],
         ['status' => 'confirmed'],
     ]),$response->getContent(), '');
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a wide range of JSON-assertions and you might be able to build what you are looking for from that.

For example you can assert for parts of the json using [`assertJsonFragment()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L472) or just whether the structure is correct, ignoring the actual content using [`assertJsonStructure()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L578).

For example you could look if the json contains the correct number of elements with the key `status` using [`assertJsonCount($number, $key)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L614).

Unfortunately there is no particular assertion that already matches your requirement, at least not by default. There might be some library out there providing it for your.